# How to define directive for input text with the keypress event in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to implement a directive in order to format input type="text" value for grouping digits, I have the method for the grouping but I have difficulties accessing the value from the directive and also to register to the keypress event from the directive.

I have the following:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="newNumberVal"                                                           
       placeholder="" name="newNumber" formControlName="newNumber" maxlength="20" groupingFormat>

import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Directive({
  selector: '[groupingFormat]'
})
export class GroupingFormatDirective {

  private el: HTMLElement;

  constructor(elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = elRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const element = this.el;    
    //how to access the input value from nativeElement and how to add event ?
  }



digitGrouping(digits) {
    //this method is able to change the digits value directly.
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ElementRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) is an Angular Wrapper on the native DOM element. Once you have access to elementRef, you have access to the DOM element and can add EventListener to it. Check out this stackBlitz demo of what you are trying to achieve https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-directive-native-ref?file=src/app/new.directive.ts

Comment: Thanks, but I need also to assign the value after format doing something like:this.el.value = this.digitGrouping(this.el.value); But this is not legal assignment.

Comment: I am not pretty sure I got your use case. Are you intending to change the input field after formatting it in the directive? Can you please elaborate a little more with an example ?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake the code this.el.value = this.digitGrouping(this.el.value); working fine. (I had problem inside the grouping method and I fixed it) this method was originally javascript and I've kind convert it to typescript! thanks!

Comment: Awesome, all the best!!